# Problem when trying to implement selection table of angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am trying to implement the selection column in my table of angular material, I follow all the steps as specified on the page: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples but it does not work for me (it does not show the column) and the sad thing is that it does not show me any errors. I leave some code:

table:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

<ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null" [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()" [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()" [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
        </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null" [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)" [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
        </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="rec_fechaAlta">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Fecha Alta</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.rec_fechaAlta }}</td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="tipRec_nombre">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Reclamo</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.tipRec_nombre }}</td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="rec_direccion">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Dirección</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.rec_direccion }}</td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="bar_nombre">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Barrio</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.bar_nombre }}</td>
</ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
</tr>
```

ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';

export interface ReclamoPendiente {
  rec_fechaAlta: string;
  tipRec_nombre: string;
  rec_direccion: string;
  bar_nombre: string;
}

let arrData: ReclamoPendiente[] = [];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-crear-orden-servicio',
  templateUrl: './crear-orden-servicio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crear-orden-servicio.component.css']
})
export class CrearOrdenServicioComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['select', 'rec_fechaAlta', 'tipRec_nombre', 
'rec_direccion', 'bar_nombre'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ReclamoPendiente>(arrData);
  selection = new SelectionModel<ReclamoPendiente>(true, []);

  ngOnInit() {
      this.objIDArServ = {
        usu_IDAreaServicio: this.user.usu_IDAreaServicio
      };

this.ordServService.selectReclamosPendientes(this.objIDArServ).subscribe(data => 
 {
    arrData = data;
    console.log(data);
 });
}

  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected()
      ? this.selection.clear()
      : this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }

  checkboxLabel(row?: any): string {
    if (!row) {
      return `${this.isAllSelected() ? 'select' : 'deselect'} all`;
    }
    return `${
      this.selection.isSelected(row) ? 'deselect' : 'select'
    } row ${row.position + 1}`;
  }
}
```

console result:

[image: CONSOLE]

screen:

[image: OUTPUT]
any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are trying to assign data to table even before data gets loaded from service.

Try something like

```
 dataSource :any
ngOnInit(){

this.ordServService.selectReclamosPendientes(this.objIDArServ).subscribe(data => 
 {
    arrData = data;
    console.log(data);
this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(arrData);
 });
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I already tried that way and it doesn't work. It shows the following error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasValue' of undefined

Comment: @AguFortini can you share the code on stackblitz, so it will be easy to debug

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you are not passing data correctly to your `dataSource`.

Where you are getting the data - try this:

```
arrData = data;
console.log(data);
this.dataSource.data = data;
```

or

```
arrData = data;
console.log(data);
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ReclamoPendiente>(data);
```

Comment: Also, if you're updating the data, you might want to declare `arrData` as a property of your `CrearOrdenServicioComponent` class.

Comment: Hi Johan! If I have tried that way, but it shows me the error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasValue' of undefined. (line 4 in html)

Comment: Yes, but in the page of angular material, the code specifies it that way. Https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples table 12

Comment: Just to see if you get any data, remove the first `mat-checkbox` element completely. does your table populate with data?

Comment: The table is filled by calling a get method in my WebApi in C# which I send a JSON and get a JSON in response..I removed the mat-checkbox, and the error no longer appears, but the data is not displayed

Comment: Hi @AguFortini, its definitely that the data is not being passed correctly to your `dataSource` property. Best practice would be to keep your data logic in a service class and use [dependecy injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)  to get access to it. I have prepared a small stackblitz app to demonstrate what I meant in my earlier comments and answer. I kept your template and logic exactly, but changed the way you get the data.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p8acp8

Comment: Hi Johan! Thanks for your time! I almost have it, it already brings me the data correctly but it does not show it to me, since I am getting the following error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined of the function .isAllSelected, specifically in the line: const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;. Try the fixed data as you proposed and show it, only it does not show the checkbox column.